# Using Java 8 java.time.LocalDate, can you compute Chinese New Year date?

Tags: java, calendar, java-8, java-time

Using ***Java 8*** `java.time.LocalDate`, can you compute *Chinese New Year date*?

Comment: See also this [JDK-issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4609228). To set your expectations, I guess support for a Chinese lunar calendar will never come in standard Java.

Comment: If I was able to answer your question, would you mind accepting it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.

The [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) states that this function uses the Gregorian calendar system. Chinese New Year is based on the Chinese calendar and lunar calendar. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_New_Year#Dates))

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not possible without an external library because standard Java does not contain a Chinese calendar. The calculation of Chinese New Year requires complex astronomical calculations, and standard Java has no astronomy support, too.

As workaround, use my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) (v4.35) and then write following code:

```
LocalDate gregorian = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Shanghai"));
ChineseCalendar cc = ChineseCalendar.ofNewYear(gregorian.getYear());
LocalDate newYearAsGregorian = cc.transform(PlainDate.axis()).toTemporalAccessor();

System.out.println(
    newYearAsGregorian); // 2018-02-16

System.out.println(
    "Year of the " 
        + cc.get(ChineseCalendar.YEAR_OF_CYCLE).getZodiac(Locale.ENGLISH));
// Year of the Dog
```

For more details, see also the [API](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/ChineseCalendar.html).